# Using XDebug with SublimeText on a WAMP server

Tags: php, xdebug

I have been hacking away at this for hours, and at one point it was actually working on a test page, but I don't know what happened since then because its stopped working. I've been getting this error a lot:

> Error:  b'Failed loading c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll\n'

Its strange because it definitely is loading the file, when I add this to my php.ini file:

```
zend_extension = "c:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.6.19\\zend_ext\\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll"
```

it tells that it is indeed enabled. In the php.ini file I spotted this: [image] In a tutorial I read, the xdebug.ini file appeared in one of those fields: [image] Heres the full settings in my php.ini file:

then check phpinfo() and I now see a section for xdebug:
[image]

Also when I run

> if (xdebug_is_enabled()) { echo 'its enabled'; }

```
[xdebug]zend_extension = "c:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.6.19\\zend_ext\\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log= "C:\\wamp\\tmp\\xdebug.log"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\\wamp\\tmp"
xdebug.collect_params = 4
xdebug.collect_return = on
xdebug.collect_vars = on
xdebug.show_local_vars = 3
```

I'll be honest, I have no idea what half of those parameters do. Heres the settings for my sublime project:

```
    "settings":
{
    "xdebug":
    {
        "url": "localhost/xdebug_test"
    },
    "sublime-view-in-browser": {
         "baseUrl": "http://localhost/xdebug_test",
         "basePath": "C:\\wamp\\www\\xdebug_test"
    }
}
```

and inside XDebug.sublime.settings I added the URL in there:

```
"url": "http://localhost/xdebug_test"
```

Heres the index file in the xdebug_test folder:

[image]

but when I start the debugger and launch the browser, it instantly echoes test, and nothing appears in the xdebug console:
[image]
 It worked on that exact file yesterday, I don't know what could have changed since then.

Is there a way to diagnose whats wrong with it? I don't think so because this isn't just happening in sublime text, heres what happens when I ran a PHP script in the terminal:
[image]

EDIT: I just spotted in phpinfo() that the IDE Key is set to PHPSTORM. Thats strange because in the xdebug settings file, its set as this:

```
"ide_key": "sublime.xdebug",
```

Could that be the issue? Is there anything I can do here to further diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, xdebug was connecting to the wrong port. I found the log file in `C:/wamp/tmp/xdebug.log`  and checked out the latest messages, and there were loads of lines saying the same thing:

> Log opened at 2016-10-21 16:09:25
>   I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001.
>   E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
>   Log closed at 2016-10-21 16:09:26

I suspected the issue was with the port, I checked the `php.ini` file and it was set to `9001`, then I checked `Xdebug.sublime-settings` and noticed the port was set to `9000`. I set the port in php.ini to 9000 and now xdebug is working.

I still don't know why its giving me those errors about not being able to load the extension. Strange because it definitely is loading them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the xdebug url in project settings?

```
"xdebug":
{
    "url": "http://localhost/xdebug_test"

}
```

Comment: I just tried changing it back to the default value "url": "" , it didn't change anything.

Comment: Ok.. also try changing xdebug.remote_host="localhost" in the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

What if you use this version of dll - https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11-nts.dll ? Postfix "nts" means "Non-thread-safe".

And of course you can use XDebug wizard to find out which dll version and which settings do you need - https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: I tried the non thread safe version and it didn't work at all, nothing showed up in phpinfo().

Answer (score 0):

I pasted my info into the wizard and heres what I got
[image]

I'll give the non threaded version a try.